# How to check if a CString contains only numeric characters

Tags: visual-c++, cstring, visual-c++-2005

I'm reading from a file and parsing its contents. I need to make sure a `CString` value consist of only numbers. What are the different methods i could achieve it?

Sample code:

```
Cstring Validate(CString str)
{
  if(/*condition to check whether its all numeric data in the string*/)
  {
     return " string only numeric characters";
  }
  else
  {
     return "string contains non numeric characters";
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you care about other languages at all?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can iterate over all characters and check with the function `isdigit` whether the character is numeric.

```
#include <cctype>

Cstring Validate(CString str)
{
    for(int i=0; i<str.GetLength(); i++) {
        if(!std::isdigit(str[i]))
            return _T("string contains non numeric characters");
    }
    return _T("string only numeric characters");
}
```

Another solution that does not use `isdigit` but only CString member functions uses [`SpanIncluding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300657%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

```
Cstring Validate(CString str)
{
    if(str.SpanIncluding("0123456789") == str)
        return _T("string only numeric characters");
    else
        return _T("string contains non numeric characters");
}
```

Comment: Could this be possible by only using `CString` function? Isnt it C++ style to use isdigit?

Comment: @Rohit I don't know of a `CString` method that checks if the whole string or parts are numeric. `isdigit` is even a C function, but it's standardized and you won't have problems using it:)

Comment: @Rohit I found a way only using CString member functions. See edit

Comment: `isdigit` assumes the input characters are bytes in the local code page, (or sometimes it assumes ASCII), and `CString` normally holds UTF-16.

Comment: Would it be a little more efficient to compare the length of the SpanIncluding result with the length of the string instead of doing a string compare? The string compare ends up comparing each character if they are identical strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **CString::Find**,

```
int Find( TCHAR ch ) const;

int Find( LPCTSTR lpszSub ) const;

int Find( TCHAR ch, int nStart ) const;

int Find( LPCTSTR pstr, int nStart ) const;
```

**Example**

```
CString str("The stars are aligned");
int n = str.Find('e')
if(n==-1)   //not found
else        //found
```

See here In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314323%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?